# Automating file edit

Tags: excel, vba, automation

I'm trying to access Excel files in a folder, change the first sheet (Sheet 1) to zoom 80%. I have all my references set up but am just getting compiling and syntax errors:

```
   Function XCEL_FILE_EDIT()

       Dim file
       Dim path As String
       Dim Documents As Excel.Worksheets
       Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet, lngZoom As Long

       path = "C:\TEST\TEST\TEST\"

       file = Dir(path & "*.xlsx")

       Do While file <> ""

          Documents.Open FileName:=(path & "*.xlsx")

          For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

             Select Case Documents.Name

                Case "Sheet 1": lngZoom = 80

             End Select

             With ws
                .Select
                ActiveWindow.Zoom = lngZoom
             End With

          Documents.Save
          Documents.Close

          file = Dir()

      Loop

   End Function
```

Comment: What errors are you getting at what lines?

Comment: For one, you want `workbooks.Open FileName:=(path & file)`. Edit: for two, `For Each ws In file.Worksheets`. And use a `sub` not `function`.

Comment: Also, instead of `With ws .select [...] End With` just replace that block with `ws.Activate` then `ActiveWindow.Zoom = lngZoom`.  `.Select` may not necessarily Activate the sheet (I'm sure it does, but I guess use `Activate` since it's a little more specific? (Someone please comment on my thinking if it's redundant or unnecessary).

Comment: Does your `for` has an end?

Answer (score 0):

Taking what others said, and making some modifications, try this:

```
Sub XCEL_FILE_EDIT()

    Dim file As String
    Dim path As String
    Dim WS As Worksheet

    path = "C:\TEST\TEST\TEST\"
    file = Dir(path & "*.xlsx")

    Do While file <> ""

        Workbooks.Open Filename:=file
        For Each WS in Workbooks(file).Sheets
            WS.Select
            Application.PrintCommunication = False
            WS.PageSetup.Zoom = 80
            Application.PrintCommunication = True
        Next WS
        Workbooks(file).Close True
        file = Dir()

    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Any idea what I'm doing wrong?as this doesn't do anything.

Comment: Sorry, I think I finally got what you were trying to do.  I saw "Sheet 1" in your initial example and thought you only wanted to change the sheet entitled "Sheet 1".  Actually the first sheet is usually entitled "Sheet1" without the space.  And upon closer examination, it looks like you wanted all the sheets to be zoomed to 80%.  So try the edited code above and see if that works for you.

Comment: It's a Run-time error 424 - object required, is that down to references?

Comment: When I run the code on my side, on two different computers but both having Excel 2010, it works fine without referencing any special libraries.  If you "debug", at what line exactly does it error out?  Is it having trouble with the PrintCommunication line?  Or does it not even compile?

Comment: I'm running it on access 2010 vba

Comment: If you are using access, rather than excel, that could be why.   I assume you were not able to isolate a specific line where the error occurred.  Sorry, I actually have not used access very much so I don't know how that could affect the code, or if it would require certain references.